# Bouncycastle dependency(bcprov-ext-jdk15on-152.jar) on Itext

Tags: itext, bouncycastle

I am using the bouncycastle latest jar(bcprov-ext-jdk15on-152.jar) and iText5.5.0. But I have noticed there are some interdependency between itext pdf and Bouncycastle for digital pdf sign and encryption is not working for both the version. 
My question is
1) If I am using the bcprov-ext-jdk15on-152.jar (latest bouncycastle jar) then is there any compatible version for itext that I can use for?
If it is not released then when we can expect the same?
2) As new bouncycastle jar heavily changed their API internally, is there any way to sign the pdf without Bouncycastle?

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated..
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

iText 5.5.0 had a dependency on BC 1.49. Please use 1.49.

Source: https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/2e490fa7671e3f667488cdd5ba3d11a142e8573c/pom.xml#L208

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the BouncyCastle version: the API changes are indeed a pain. Always check the POM file of a specific version to find out which BouncyCastle version to use because using the wrong version can seriously break your code.

If you need another version of BouncyCastle in your code (e.g. because of another dependency), you can opt to use the Android port of iText ([iTextG](http://itextpdf.com/product/itextg)). iTextG is almost identical to iText, but it depends on SpongyCastle instead of BouncyCastle. SpongyCastle is almost identical to BouncyCastle, but it was created because Android devices ship with an older version of BouncyCastle that clashes with the one needed by iText.

As for your question: can you sign a PDF document without using BouncyCastle? The answer is yes, but then you need to use another library and write your own `ExternalSignatureContainer`.